# How to insert slashed o "ø" into an author's name in my bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, accents

In my bibliography I have a reference to an author with a Danish name: Nørregaard.
The problem is that to do the slashed o I need to type `\o`. However, I can't do this `N\orregaard` and if I do this `N\o rregaard` then I get a space in the name. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You don't get a space if you type `N\o rregard`.

Comment: With the right input encoding you should be able to insert »ø« directly.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

When typing the name in the text, `N\o rregard` will not leave any space in the output, as spaces after control sequences (with name consisting of letters) are ignored.

However, in `.bib` file the question is slightly different, as you want to use the name also for collation. The BibTeX manual recommends

```
author = {N{\o}rregard, X.}
```

because in this way the entire combination `{\o}` would be regarded simply as an "o". The typeset text will not have font dependent kerning between "N" and "ø" and between "ø" and "r". If you're using `biblatex`, then `Nørregard` is fine (as long as you use an input encoding where `ø` is present).

Comment: What are required packages to get $\o$ in the main document? It would be nice to get a complete answer.

Comment: @Masi Why should you want ø in math mode? And for getting ø (with `\o`) in text mode no package is needed.

Comment: You are right! $\emptyset$ better. I thought you could do that wdth \o but not apparently.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is an ALT Code for the letter
 Simply hold down alt and type in the corresponding code for your letter on the numeric keypad
 Ø is alt 0216
 ø is alt 0248

If you need to find another special letter this website is helpful

https://usefulshortcuts.com/alt-codes/accents-alt-codes.php

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Thank you for your answer. I am not sure the question is about obtaining the sign with the keyboard, rather than obtaining the sign in the output pdf, see the accepted answer. In any case thanks again.

Comment: In that case one needs to make sure that the document is encoded correctly and that LaTeX knows about this. Also note that BibTeX (we are specifically talking about bibliographies here) can not sort non-ASCII chars, which could lead to undesired results if for example Ø is the initial letter of a name.

Comment: These codes are specific to Windows systems, other systems have something equivalent.  Make sure that the document is encoded as utf8 and then all will work smoothly in a LaTeX from April 2018 onwards.